# How to remove file association with a program for files with no file type?

Tags: windows, windows-7, file-type, windows-explorer, file-association

On my current Windows 7 machine, all files with no file type/extension are associated with a program. When I double click on the file, instead of prompting for which program I want to use, it tries to open it with said program (in this case Mass Effect 2). How would I remove this association, as 'File' with no extension is not listed in the Windows extension manager.

I looked at this page [here](https://superuser.com/questions/13653/how-to-set-the-default-program-for-opening-files-without-an-extension-in-windows), but I don't currently have a registry entry there, so it must be something else?

I'd like to either remove this association, or at least change it to Notepad++ (what I normally use to open files with no extension). I hope I've phrased this question correctly, as you can see this is my first one. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even realize that it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key you are looking for is **`hklm:software/classes/unknown`**. I have mine set as Notepad2

```c
sp hklm:software/classes/unknown/shell '(default)' edit
ni hklm:software/classes/unknown/shell/edit/command `
  -f -t expandstring -va '"%programfiles%/notepad2/notepad2" %1'
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/cb904d3/windows.ps1#L12-L14)